# Catching the Parse kPFErrorConnectionFailed error-code & Cancelling the pullToRefresh’s UIActivityIndicatorView in the IOS PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiactivityindicatorview, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I have two questions as follows:

- I will like to catch the kPFErrorConnectionFailed error-code from the query in the IOS PFQueryTableViewController’s queryForTable. How do I go about it?
- After the last attempt to connect to Network and I receive  [Error]: Network connection failed, How do I cancel the pullToRefresh’s UIActivityIndicatorView which currently continues to load indefinitely?

What I’ve tried:

- Concerning catching error-code kPFErrorConnectionFailed, I tried the following (which does not catch the error):

  `- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
      [super objectsDidLoad:error];
      if(error.code == kPFErrorConnectionFailed)
      {…}
  }`

Comment: Don't be selective: `if(error) NSLog(@"error", error);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A work around for Catching kPFErrorConnectionFailed is to use [Apple's Reachability Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to check if the Parse Network Server is reachable before trying to load data.
- A fix to the indefinite pullToRefresh UIActivityIndicatorView is to use kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork as opposed to the kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly. The kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly keeps trying to load data from the network even with a bad connection. However, kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork relies on the cached data when the network server is unreachable. Check [here](https://parse.com/questions/what-is-the-benefit-of-kpfcachepolicycachethennetwork) for more information